# Passing method with parameters with constructor

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have a Manager class DataManger.cs, which contains a method to get data from a specific person.

```
public class DataManager
{
    public DataType GetDataByIdNameAge (uint id, string name, int age)
    {...}   
}
```

And I have Builder class, which creates Office classes:

```
public class Builder
{
    private DataManager _dataManager;

    public Builder()
    {
        _dataManager = new DataManager();
    }

    // Creates multiple Office objects
    public void Create()
    {
        var office = new Office();
    }
}

public class Office
{
    private Func<UInt32, UInt32, UInt32> _getDataByIdNameAge { get; }

    public Office(Func<uint, string, int> getDataByIdNameAge )
    {
        _getDataByIdNameAge = getDataByIdNameAge ;
    }

}
```

Now I want to pass the method GetDataByIdNameAge (uint id, string name, int age) to each created Office object and use it there. But I don't now how to create the Office object to pass the method.

Comment: You could just inherit from class `DataManager` then the method would be available via `inheritance`

Comment: Note that the last parameter of `Func` is the return value (if there is none, use `Action`). Also, you have a mismatch between `_getDataByIdNameAge ` and `getDataByIdNameAge ` in terms of the types.

Comment: `new Office(() => new DataManager().GetDataByIdNameAge)`? But your return types are wonky and your parameter types don't match. Create a [mcve].

Comment: I've added DataType to the method

Comment: How does the `Builder` gets an instance of `DataManager`? I don't see any `DataManager` references in the office nor the Builder class. How are these related

Comment: This is a simplified example of my problem. Now I've added the DataManager instance to the Builder. 

@CodeCaster I've tried your solution but I get this error: Delegate 'Func<uint, string, uint>' does not take 0 arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the methodname without parentheses.

```
public class DataManager
{
    public DataType GetDataByIdNameAge (uint id, string name, int age)
    {...}   
}


public class Builder
{
    private DataManager _dataManager;

    public Builder()
    {
        _dataManager = new DataManager();
    }

    // Creates multiple Office objects
    public void Create()
    {
        var office = new Office(_dataManager.GetDataByIdNameAge);  // <---
    }
}

public class Office
{
    // LMFTFU                        
    private Func<uint, string, int, DataType> _getDataByIdNameAge { get; }
    //                              ^^^^^^^^ don't forget the return datatype

    public Office(Func<uint, string, int, DataType> getDataByIdNameAge )
    {
        _getDataByIdNameAge = getDataByIdNameAge;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but at the line 'var office = new Office...' I get this error: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<uint, string, int>

Comment: @AndRoid my bad, forgot the returntype: DataType. I've updated it. Your function declaration should be `Func<uint, string, int, DataType>`Like John said, the last generic is the return type

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to abstract out the DataManager to an IDataManager interface, then Office would have an IDataManager object that it would use for any "data management", like this:

```
public class DataType
{
}

public interface IDataManager
{
    DataType GetDataByIdNameAge(uint id, string name, int age);
}

public class DataManager : IDataManager
{
    public DataType GetDataByIdNameAge(uint id, string name, int age)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Builder
{
    // Creates multiple Office objects
    public void Create()
    {
        var office = new Office(new DataManager());
    }
}

public class Office
{
    private IDataManager dataManager;

    public Office(IDataManager dataManager)
    {
        this.dataManager = dataManager;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DataType dataType = dataManager.GetDataByIdNameAge(1, "SomeName", 18);
    }
}
```

I think this is more elegant than passing the details of the method around as a Func.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, I want to prevent that every Office object hasg a DataManager object.